# Wi-fi cannot be turned on on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I would like to mention that this is my first time installing any Linux distribution so I don't have much experience. 
A few days ago I decided to install Ubuntu on my laptop that was just sitting around. I had some trouble with the install and when I finally got it installed I couldn't connect to Wi-Fi. Got the ethernet cable plugged in, googled the issue but none of the things I found were helpful. I tried running rfkill and this is what I got:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
1 wlan      phy0   unblocked   blocked
```

A common fix that I found was to use the Wi-Fi key, but my laptop does not have one (it has an airplane mode key but that didn't do anything)
I also tried running

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

but that had no effect either. In the BIOS I didn't find anything Wi-Fi related. Everything worked fine until I got Ubuntu so I suppose it's not a hardware issue of any kind.
I don't know how helpful this is but I will also mention I'm using a HP Omen (15t) laptop. In a few threads I saw people asking for lsmod so I'm going to put that here:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
ttm                   106496  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
coretemp               16384  0
kvm                   593920  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
arc4                   16384  2
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
pcbc                   16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
videodev              184320  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
iwlmvm                364544  0
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
mac80211              778240  1 iwlmvm
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
input_leds             16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
iwlwifi               282624  1 iwlmvm
aesni_intel           188416  2
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
serio_raw              16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
cfg80211              622592  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
mei_me                 40960  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
i915                 1617920  13
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
video                  45056  1 i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
psmouse               147456  0
r8169                  86016  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
rtsx_pci               65536  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  7 i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler        53248  1 ipmi_devintf
```

EDIT: Output for

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Edit 2: Tried turning airplane mode on, rebooted and turned it back off yet nothing changed probably because I did it from the OS because shortcut key for airplane mode doesn't work at all in Linux

Comment: `Hard blocked: yes` indicates (at least to me) that the connection is blocked by hardware. This could be a switch, a key combo or a BIOS setting. Try turning airplane mode on, rebooting and then turning airplane mode off.